# Obtaining site's HTML after GET that returns JSON

Tags: html, json, vba, winhttprequest

### Introduction

*The main question is way down, but I guess it'd help to have some background in this case*

Ok, so I'd like to start by saying that this is actually my first question on stackoverflow - I have been using this site for ages, and I basically learned everything I know about coding from it, but that also means I have huge gaps in my knowledge - a lot of the methods I use are chosen just because they are the only ones I know - if you have any suggestion how I can improve the process described below, do not hesitate to share them with me. I would also like to apologize in advance if my request is in any way unclear, I'll try to elaborate in any such case.

### Method

I am trying to crawl individual players' performance in UEFA Champions League matches (I'm actually building a Fantasy Football app, a project I reckon I'll have many questions about in the future as well). My source are the UEFA statistics sites, e.g. "http://www.uefa.com/uefachampionsleague/season=2016/matches/live/index.html?day=2&session=1&match=2015684". There, about in the middle you can choose "PLAYER" statistics, and see a "table" (actually it's a div with lists) where (by default) statistics concerning given (single) match are presented. When fully loaded in HTML there are two divs, one for match stats, one for overall, some elements of the lists are hidden (based on the position of the player for example), but all are there. The part that I'm interested in looks like this:

```
<div id="matchTab" class="tab-panel rounded-down scrollable ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" aria-labelledby="ui-id-7" role="tabpanel" aria-expanded="true" aria-hidden="false">
<div class="tab-content">
<div class="col-stats">
<ul class="goals-table stats">
<li style="display: list-item;">
Goals scored
<span class="value goals-scored">1</span>
</li>
<li style="display: none;">
<li class="bg-highlight" style="display: none;">
<li style="display: none;">
<li class="bg-highlight" style="display: none;">
</ul>
<ul class="attempts-table stats" style="display: block;">
<ul class="passes-attempt-table stats">
<ul class="fouls-table fouls-table-gk stats">
</div>
<div class="col-stats">
</div>
</div>
```

(Most of the code is collapsed)

Right now I am using WinHTTPRequest in VBA, hoping to populate an Excel range with data, but in the end I will move the project to VB.NET and use SQL. The problem is that I don't seem to be able to obtain the date presented in the list. Using:

```
whReq.Open "GET", "http://www.uefa.com/uefachampionsleague/season=2016/matches/live/index.html?day=2&session=1&match=2015684"
```

Returns only the main structure of the side, not the data from the "table". I therefore used FireBug, and then WireShark to inspect the data that's being transferred when a player is changed in the selection. One packet is general stats about the player, his age, name, etc. - useless. The second one looks like this:

```
GET /livecommon/match-centre/cup=1/season=2016/round=2000634/player=103697/overall.json?v=1448115572662
```

(The "v" parameter is actually useless, works the same way without it)
which actually does return a bunch of data. Apparently it's in the form of JSON, and looks for example like this:

```
{"Players":null,"OverallStat":{"250021048":{"PlayerId":250021048,"TeamId":0,"MatchesPlayed":3,"MinutesPlayed":188,"GoalsScored":0,"GoalsConceded":0,"GoalsByMinute":0,"GoalsByAttempts":0,"TotalAttempts":2,"Assist":0,"Saves":0,"SavesOnAttempts":0,"SavesByMinutes":0,"FoulsCommitted":3,"FoulsCommittedByMinute":63,"FoulsSuffered":0,"FoulsSufferedByMinute":0,"FoulsPenalty":0,"FoulsSuffPenalty":0,"YellowCard":0,"RedCard":0,"Passes":149,"PassingDistribution":0,"PassesCompleted":68,"PassesAttempted":81,"PassingAccuracy":84,"Delivery":0,"Run":2,"AttempsOn":0,"AttempsOff":2,"Offside":1,"ShotHittingPost":0,"HittingBar":0,"ShotBlocked":2,"Corners":0,"Attacks":0,"BigChance":0,"BallPossession":0,"DistanceCovered":18655,"ClearancesAttempted":4,"ClearancesCompleted":3,"Blocked":0,"TackleCompleted":0,"TackleWrong":0}},"LastUpdatedCET":"05 November 2015, 11:47 CET","LastUpdateDay":5,"LastUpdateMonth":11,"LastUpdateYear":2015,"LastUpdateHour":11,"LastUpdateMinute":47}
```

And this it the kind of response that is obtained whenever a player is changed, no matter whether single match statistics or overall are chosen (of course one does not have to actually be on the site, no cookies are needed, just "http://www.uefa.com/livecommon/match-centre/cup=1/season=2016/round=2000634/player=250021048/overall.json" and there you have the statistics)
The thing is, those are overall statistics. I could understand there is some kind of code that calculates statistics for individual match (I can actually do with that myself, just refresh data after each match to calculate the statistics from individual matches). Nevertheless, they tend to update the statistics irregularly, so I would really prefer to be able to retrieve stats from individual matches. So:

### Question

Given the above, is there a way to obtain the html of the site after the another GET for player statistics, **using WinHTTPRequest**? If not, what could be the best way? I did try working with InternetExplorer object, but was unable to produce any results at all (I actually had the same problem at work, where I needed to access our company's site - I couldn't even check for readystate, over site's worked, but I guess it's a topic for another question)

Thanks in advance, and again, sorry if anything I wrote is unclear.

Comment: The data are loaded via ajax in the functions ```loadPlayerMatchStat``` and ```loadMatchStat```. Examine those functions and you will see that the url of ajax calls are composed in functions ```getPlayerFeedPaths``` and ```getFeedPaths```. The feed-paths functions can provide the following json files ```players.match.json, teams.match.json, overall.json, domestic.json``` and the ```data.html```. So it might be possible to simulate those feed-path functions and to compose the url for data you need and get corresponding json data.

Comment: To parse json you can use e.g. VBJSON which is a VB6 adaptation of the VBA JSON project and can be fuound [here](http://code.google.com/p/vba-json/).

Comment: I see, It did seem like some other "stuff" was involved. As I said, I do have huge gaps in my knowledge, and the whole "web-sites" thing is one of them. Nevertheless, it's a great opportunity to learn a little. Thank you so much for your help!